# How to debug minified javascript on production?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a front end single page app deployed on S3. It is minified on production. 
It creates error only when it is minified via grunt on production.
I cannot repro the issue in dev.
How do I go about debugging such issue?

Thank you.

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'")**. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Chrome debugger will allow you to expand minified code into multiple lines to make it easier to step through and set breakpoints in it.  It has a `{}` symbol below the code window.  When you click on it, it expands multiple statements per line into one line per statement and indents code so you can then read it and step through it.  It doesn't do anything about those "hard to read" single letter variables since the meaningful names for minimized variables are gone at this point, but it does allow you to use the minified code in the debugger.